# Peach blend wine popping corks and very fizzy

Tags: carbonation

I made a batch of peach blend vinters best wine base. I intentionally added extra sugar as I always do. The majority of residual sugar was converted to alcohol. I racked several times. I then filtered with my vine brite filter system. I degassed a few times. I back sweetened to taste. Let it rest another week with the airlock in place. I then degassed again and bottled. My new wine rack is in my dining room in direct sunlight.

- Could the fluctuation of temperatures be the cause of corks popping?

I currently have it in my garage beverage fridge in boxes.

- What is the best solution to my problem?

I currently only have 16 bottles left. We have been trying to drink it faster than the others. I have been making wine for 8 years and this is only the second time I have had this problem.

- Would Camden tablets before bottling have possibly prevented this from happening?

I think I may have forgotten to use them in this batch. My notes taken during each batch usually show me where I went wrong. Thanks, I have two other batches going now ready for bottling. Blackberry and Blueberry.

Comment: Was this intended to be a carbonated wine?

Answer (score 1):

A few degrees shouldn't expand enough to pop a cap or cork.

**Sounds like yeast action**. Campden would help but not much as it only prevents growth, not feeding.

Keep em cellar cool and out of light. Give them a safe place to finish off and the yeast to go dormant. If you corked you should be ok with a dry cork. Then wet with side storage after yeast is done. Caps: may need burped or replaced after they breach.

Answer (score 1):

The fluctuation of temperature will cause a fluctuation in bottle pressure because the volume of co2 dissolved in solution is dependant on temp. The higher temperature goes, the lower co2 that can be dissolved in solution will be and the higher the pressure will go.

What is your bottling temp? by raising it you will reduce pressure

How much head space have you left? by leaving a larger volume headspace you could reduce the maximum pressure reached by the same tempearature. If the fluid level is lowered then the pressure increase per tempearture increase will be reduced because the amount of co2 leaving solution is reduced and the amount of compressable gas is increased.

[This pdf](http://ganauamerica.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/07/Bottling-Handbook_English.pdf) shows the recommended fill level based on the bottling temperature as well how a standard 63.5 mm, 68 degree fill's pressure will vary by temperature, though they attribute this to liquid density changes rather than co2 in solution.

Answer (score 0):

Small fluctuations in temperature should not be causing the corks to pop out.

My guess would be you had excess residual sugar and the yeast is happily turning it to CO2 and forcing out the corks. Either that or you have contamination from another yeast.

Campden tablets would have likely reduced the chance of this occurring.

I feel your best course of action is to either drink it all, or recork the bottles.